# How to pass a variable in a wordpress/woocommerce $tabs callback function?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to add a variable/parameter to a callback function of a new custom woocommerce tab?

My code is the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    global $post, $woocommerce;
    // Adds the new tab
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
            $tabs["vak{$i}"] = array(
            'title'     => __(get_post_meta( $post->ID, "_vak{$i}_name", true ), 'woocommerce'),
            'priority'  => 50,
            'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content',
            );
    }

    return $tabs;

}
function woo_new_product_tab_content($i) {
    echo "Hello World!{$i}";
}
```

In this example, I want to pass the `$i` variable to the callback function.

Any help on how to achive this would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
'callback' => function( $i ){
    echo "Hello World!{$i}";
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this is accepted, since the value of `$i` will be the name of the tab, and not the value of `$i` defined outside the function, which is what the OP was trying to do..

Comment: @wickywills is correct. Callback function parameter is always name of the tab regardless the variable passed.

Comment: This solution worked https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/252146/dynamically-create-callback-functions-inside-a-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
'callback' => function () use ($i) {
    echo "Hello World!{$i}";
},
```